# JCombobox editable enabled

Tags: java, jcombobox

What is the difference between the setEditable() and the setEnabled() in a jCombobox? Can a combobox be editable but not enabled and other way around? In which situation would you use which method?

Can you imagine a situation in which you would do setEnabled(false) together with setEditable(true)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`setEditable(boolean)` determines if the `JComboBox` allows text entry in addition to selecting a value via pull-down.

`setEnabled(boolean)` determines if the `JComboBox` is able to be interacted with at all.  If it is not enabled, it is displayed as grayed out.

A `JComboBox` can have any mix of these properties -

- `setEditable(true)` + `setEnabled(true)` = `JComboBox` allows text input in addition to pull down values and user can interact with it.
- `setEditable(false)` + `setEnabled(true)` = `JComboBox` only allows values from the pull down to be selected and user can interact with it.
- `setEditable(true)` + `setEnabled(false)` = `JComboBox` allows text input in addition to pull down values but user cannot interact with it.
- `setEditable(false)` + `setEnabled(false)` = `JComboBox` only allows values from the pull down to be selected and user cannot interact with it.

A situation where you may have a `JComboBox` with `setEnabled(false)` and `setEditable(true)` would be where you want a `JComboBox` that allows text input, but the form is in a state where the value of the `JComboBox` isn't applicable.  You would usually have some action that would call `setEnabled(true)` on the `JComboBox` once it does become applicable.

For example, if you have something like a student housing form, there may be a question on the form like 'Do you need a parking space?' with a `JCheckbox`. There's a `JComboBox` for the brand of car and a `JTextFied` for the license plate number.  You may have the `JComboBox` pre-populated with common car brands - Ford, Chevy, Toyota, Honda, etc. - but decide you also want to allow it to be editable in case someone owns something like a Lamborghini (and is staying in student housing - yeah, right...).  The value for car brand and license plate number aren't needed unless the user selects the `JCheckBox` signifying that they need a parking space.  You would add a listener to the `JCheckBox` that would call `setEnabled(true)` on the `JComboBox` and `JTextField` when it was selected, and `setEnabled(false)` when it wasn't.

Comment: A non editable JComboBox displays the selected item in the field, but the selection cannot be modified.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setEditable-boolean-

Answer (score 7):

If you call [`setEditable(true)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setEditable(boolean)), the JComboBox's text field becomes editable, allowing the user to type text with the keyboard in addition to selecting an item from the list.

If you call `setEnabled(false)`, the entire control becomes disabled, preventing the user from interacting with it at all.

Answer (score 1):

SetEnable() - Enables the combo box so that items can be selected.

SetEditable() - Determines whether the JComboBox field is editable.